# Gridview remains in Edit Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Gridview refuses to exit edit mode.  When I hit press the Update link, everything works as it should as far as the database being updated, but the Gridview row remains in edit mode.  When I press the Cancel button, the Gridview reflects the new information.  Why does the row remain in Edit Mode even after setting the EditIndex to -1?

I'm sure it's something really remedial, but I can't find any help with getting a gridview out of edit mode that doesn't just tell me to set the edit index.

```
protected void Gridview_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) {
    // Update code is here and works fine
    try {
        // this works and updates the database w/ no problems
        ObjectDataSource.Update();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    Gridview.EditIndex = -1;
    Gridview.DataBind();            
}
```

EDIT: I took out the try/catch and nothing seems to fail, but I do still have to explicitly call the ObjectDataSource.Update()  So, here's the setup for my GridView:

```
<asp:Gridview ID="Gridview" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource" DataKeyNames="ID" OnDataBound="Gridiew_DataBound"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="Gridview_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="Gridview_RowUpdating">
```

And the ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource" runat="server" TypeName="DAL.Class" SelectMethod="SelectMethod" UpdateMethod="UpdateMethod">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="param1" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="param2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="param3" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="param4" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="param5" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="param6" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="param7" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="param8" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

So, what is set up incorrectly, that it isn't automatically updating?

EDIT 2:
So, I'm now setting the parameter values in the ObjectDataSource_Updating event (which wasn't being called before which is why I had the explicit called to the ods_update()).  Now the _Updating event is being hit, but it never goes into my DAL method.  Again, no errors are thrown, it just doesn't do anything....

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone, make sure you update your Edit Index after update/cancel:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = -1
```

That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something bad is happening like the edit is failing.
And since you are hiding errors:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

...you can't see what's happening.

If the GridView/DataSource is setup properly, you don't need to explicitly call Update or DataBind.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the original post with my gridview/ods set up in the aspx.  So, what have I done wrong that is preventing it from updating w/o the explicit call in the row_updating?

Comment: Try removing the code in the Updating Event.  If you want to reset the Index, do it in the Updated Event.

Comment: No difference.  I don't really want to reset the index, I was just doing that because it wasn't coming out of edit mode on it's own.  I don't understand why I'm having to explicitly call the update() to begin with...

Comment: one more thing - please put proper IDs to your controls. not saying that this is the reason for your issue. But it will be a good practise. in your case - give a more better ID for your GridView

Comment: did u try the updated event as suggested above by @SteveWellens

Comment: I did.  It made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a shot by updating a dummy table? (in Gridview_RowUpdating event)

```
 ObjectDataSource.UpdateCommand = @"UPDATE somedummytable set  parameter";   
ObjectDataSource.Update();     
Gridview.EditIndex = -1;       
    ObjectDataSource.DataBind();     
Gridview.DataBind();
```

After this step, I am sure it will come out of edit mode.